# Why is my sieve of Eratosthenes code looping infinitely. I have tested with a few numbers

Tags: c++, loops, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to implement The sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in C++, from the pseudo code below:

> Input: an integer n > 1.
>
> Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n,
>   initially all set to true.
>
> for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
>   if A[i] is true:
>    for j = i2, i2+i, i2+2i, i2+3i, ..., not exceeding n:
>     A[j] := false.
>
> Output: all i such that A[i] is true.

However my code loops infinitely in the last for loop and I can't figure out why.

```
void primes(int n)
{
    bool numArr[n];
    for (int a=2;a<n;a++)
       {
           numArr[a]=true;
       }
    int   k,j, m = int(sqrt(n));
    for(int i=2;i<m;i++)

    {
        k=0;
        if(numArr[i]==true)
        {
            for(j=i^2;j<n;j+(k*i))
            {
                numArr[j]=false;
                k++;
            }

        }

    }

    for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(numArr[j]==true)
        {
            cout<<numArr[j]<<endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems like a *perfect* time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also note that C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. And remember that uninitialized elements of an array or a vector really are uninitialized. Even reading their indeterminate values lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C++.

Comment: And are you sure about `j=i^2`? You do know that the `^` operator is the *bitwise exclusive or* operator?

Comment: It's not the last loop that lasts forever. You could have spotted this bug by printing `j` in each iteration of the previous inner loop. It's also easier to spot if you use the space bar now and then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are no VLAs in C++. Some compilers will tolerate them nevertheless, others won't. For a portable solution, `std::vector` works very well. Replace your VLA with this:

```
std::vector<bool> numArr(n);
```

You can even put the initialization into this. No need for that loop that sets everything to `true`, just change the `numArr(n)` to `numArr(n, true)` and it's all done for you.

Your main problem is here, however:

```
for(j=i^2;j<n;j+(k*i))
```

`j=i^2` doesn't do what you think it does and your increment of `j+(k*i)` doesn't increase anything. Actually, the `k` part makes no sense. Do this instead:

```
for (j = i*i; j < n; j += i)
```

Your print of `cout<<numArr[j]<<endl;` is wrong, too. `numArr[j]` is a `bool`, so that's going to print a `1` every time. Surely you wanted to print `j` instead of `numArr[j]`.

And while it's not a problem, you don't have to write `if (numArr[i] == true)`. Just do `if (numArr[i])` instead. `numArr[i]` is already a `bool`.